# Passing argument to this command line tool correctly

Tags: powershell

I am teaching myself PowerShell, an exercise I am doing is to create a function for an external tool I use all the time, this tool is ImageMagick

The function is supposed to generate, a image with a caption.

Where I am stuck on is, within the function, passing my arguments to ImageMagick:

```
Function NewImage-Magick{
    param(
        $Destination,

        [string]$Dimentions,
        [String]$PointSize,
        [string]$Font,
        [string]$BackgroundColor,
        [string]$Fill,
        [string]$Value,
        [string]$BorderColor,
        [String]$BorderStroke
    )
    Begin
        {
            switch ($PSBoundParameters.Keys){
                'PointSize'       {$PointSize = "-PointSize $PointSize"}
                'Font'            {$Font = "-font $Font"}
                'BackgroundColor' {$BackgroundColor = "-background $BackgroundColor"}
                'Fill'            {$Fill = "-fill $Fill"}
                'Value'           {$Value = "label:""$value"""}
                'BorderColor'     {$BorderColor = "-bordercolor $BorderColor"}
                'BorderStroke'    {$BorderStroke = "-border $BorderStroke"}
                }
        }
    Process{
             "``( $PointSize $Font $BackgroundColor $Fill $Value ``) $BorderColor $BorderStroke $Destination"   #Visual feedback on how string is passed to Magick
            # . "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe"  `( $PointSize $Font $BackgroundColor $Fill $Value `) $BorderColor $BorderStroke $Destination   #Passing all values to Magick
    }
}
```

```
NewImage-ImageMagic -Font arial -Fill white -BackgroundColor black -BorderColor red -BorderStroke 10 -Value "Hello World!" -Destination "c:\temp\test.png"
```

With the above invocation, if the function is set to only output a string, rather than call Magick, it will output, the following:

```
`( -font arial -background black -fill white label:"Hello World!" `) -bordercolor red -border 10 c:\temp\test.png       # "`(" is to escape powershell syntax, also Magick requires that there be a space witin both opening and closing parenthesis
```

But when I swap these two lines, so that Magick gets called with my arguments:

```
# "``( $PointSize $Font $BackgroundColor $Fill $Value ``) $BorderColor $BorderStroke $Destination"   #Visual feedback on how string is passed to Magick
. "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe"  `( $PointSize $Font $BackgroundColor $Fill $Value `) $BorderColor $BorderStroke $Destination   #Passing all values to Magick
```

The function just hangs indefinitely, until I cancel and return the prompt.

On the terminal, doing something like this, works, a file gets generated:

```
Magick  -fill red label:HellWorld  C:\TEMP\test.png
```

but doing the following returns an error:

```
$Fill = "-fill red"
Magick  $Fill label:HellWorld C:\TEMP\test.png
magick.exe: unrecognized option `-fill red' at CLI arg 2 @ fatal/magick-cli.c/ProcessCommandOptions/659.     #<<===== ERROR
```

The above is essentially what I am trying to achieve with my function,

So the questions I have in mind:

- what is causing my function to hang until I have to force cancel?
- How I can I use variables as stand ins when I am using Command Line tools in PowerShell? `Magick  $Fill label:HellWorld C:\TEMP\test.png`, rather than `Magick  -fill red label:HellWorld  C:\TEMP\test.png`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get this error

> unrecognized option `-fill red'

because PowerShell automatically quotes variables that are passed to native applications. In effect this passes `"-fill red"` as a single argument to ImageMagick, although it should be two **separate** tokens `-fill` and `red`.

To fix this, pass argument name and value as an array of two elements. Use [argument splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3) to unroll the array into separate arguments.

```bash
$Fill = '-fill', 'red'  # Array of two strings
Magick @Fill label:HellWorld C:\TEMP\test.png
```

Applied to your full code sample:

```bash
Function NewImage-Magick{
    param(
        $Destination,

        [string]$Dimentions,
        [String]$PointSize,
        [string]$Font,
        [string]$BackgroundColor,
        [string]$Fill,
        [string]$Value,
        [string]$BorderColor,
        [String]$BorderStroke
    )

    $magickArgs = @(
        switch ($PSBoundParameters.Keys){
            'PointSize'       { '-PointSize', $PointSize }
            'Font'            { '-font', $Font}
            'BackgroundColor' { '-background', $BackgroundColor}
            'Fill'            { '-fill', $Fill }
            'Value'           { "label:$value" }  # Exception: ONE token!
            'BorderColor'     { '-bordercolor', $BorderColor }
            'BorderStroke'    { '-border', $BorderStroke }
        }
    )

    . 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe' @magickArgs $Destination
}
```

**Remarks:**

- `$magickArgs = @(…)` uses the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#array-subexpression-operator--) to ensure the variable always is an array, even if only one of the optional arguments is passed to `NewImage-Magick`. This is a requirement to use the variable for [argument splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3).
- Within the `switch` statement simply use PowerShell's *implicit output* behavior to add values to the `$magickArgs` variable. Expressions that are not immediately assigned become implicit output, which can be captured at a higher level. When multiple values are captured, PowerShell automatically creates an array.
- `@magickArgs` this is where argument splatting happens and PowerShell unrolls the array into separate arguments, quoting as necessary. Strictly spoken, in this case the `@` isn't necessary, you could also write `$magickArgs`, because PowerShell defaults to splatting when passing arrays to native commands. Though using `@` always is good practice, as it makes intention clear and provides consistent syntax.
- Finally, the mandatory argument `$Destination` is appended, which showcases how you can mix splatting with normal argument passing.
- Note that I've removed the `Begin` and `Process` blocks, as your current code doesn't use the pipeline, so these blocks are pointless. Read [about Functions Advanced Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.3) if you actually want to use pipeline processing.

Comment: >because PowerShell automatically quotes variables that are passed to native applications. I aah I see. Man, it seems in powershell there is always an apt reason for anything.  I was really smashing my head against the wall on this. Your approach is so succinct, thanks allot for taking the effort to do this. I learnt allot by your example!